# Zipline issue with SPY data

Tags: finance, backtesting, quantitative

I have written a strategy to backtest in zipline, and every time I ran the backtest, and error is showed with the line: IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

After a bit of research, I suspect that there is an issue with the SPY data that Zipline collect to calculate the sharpe ratio of the strategy(returns of the Benchmarking are calculated).

The source of the error is the followin:

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
     72                              capital_base = 100000,
     73                              handle_data = handle_data,
---> 74                              data = panel)

c:\users\nicolas\lib\site-packages\zipline\utils\run_algo.py in run_algorithm(start, end, initialize, capital_base, handle_data, before_trading_start, analyze, data_frequency, data, bundle, bundle_timestamp, trading_calendar, metrics_set, default_extension, extensions, strict_extensions, environ)
    396         metrics_set=metrics_set,
    397         local_namespace=False,
--> 398         environ=environ,
    399     )

c:\users\nicolas\lib\site-packages\zipline\utils\run_algo.py in _run(handle_data, initialize, before_trading_start, analyze, algofile, algotext, defines, data_frequency, capital_base, data, bundle, bundle_timestamp, start, end, output, trading_calendar, print_algo, metrics_set, local_namespace, environ)
    173             )
    174     else:
--> 175         env = TradingEnvironment(environ=environ)
    176         choose_loader = None
    177

c:\users\nicolas\lib\site-packages\zipline\finance\trading.py in **init**(self, load, bm_symbol, exchange_tz, trading_calendar, asset_db_path, future_chain_predicates, environ)
     97             trading_calendar.day,
     98             trading_calendar.schedule.index,
---> 99             self.bm_symbol,
    100         )
    101

c:\users\nicolas\lib\site-packages\zipline\data\loader.py in load_market_data(trading_day, trading_days, bm_symbol, environ)
    154         last_date,
    155         now,
--> 156         environ,
    157     )
    158

c:\users\nicolas\lib\site-packages\zipline\data\loader.py in ensure_treasury_data(symbol, first_date, last_date, now, environ)
    262     first_date = max(first_date, loader_module.earliest_possible_date())
    263 
--> 264     data = _load_cached_data(filename, first_date, last_date, now, 'treasury',environ)
    265     if data is not None:
    266         return data

c:\users\nicolas\lib\site-packages\zipline\data\loader.py in _load_cached_data(filename, first_date, last_date, now, resource_name, environ)
    308             data = from_csv(path)
    309             data.index = data.index.to_datetime().tz_localize('UTC')
--> 310             if has_data_for_dates(data, first_date, last_date):
    311                 return data
    312

c:\users\nicolas\lib\site-packages\zipline\data\loader.py in has_data_for_dates(series_or_df, first_date, last_date)
     84     if not isinstance(dts, pd.DatetimeIndex):
     85         raise TypeError("Expected a DatetimeIndex, but got %s." % type(dts))
---> 86     first, last = dts[[0, -1]]
     87     return (first <= first_date) and (last >= last_date)
     88

c:\users\nicolas\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\base.py in **getitem**(self, key)
    173             attribs['freq'] = freq
    174 
--> 175             result = getitem(key)
    176             if result.ndim > 1:
    177                 return result

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

And the data panel constructor is :

data = OrderedDict()
ticker = "BTC_USD"

data["BTC_USD"] =  pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Nicolas/Documents/{}.csv".format(ticker),index_col = 0, parse_dates = True)

data["BTC_USD"] = data["BTC_USD"].resample("D").mean()
data["BTC_USD"] = data["BTC_USD"].fillna(method='ffill')

data["BTC_USD"] = data["BTC_USD"][["open","high","low","close","volume"]]

panel = pd.Panel(data)
panel.minor_axis = ["open","high","low","close","volume"]
panel.major_axis = panel.major_axis.tz_localize(pytz.utc)

I don't know specifically what the problem is. I look at the source code of zipline data , and loader but don't find any clue to solve the issue.

Thanks in advance for your help.
Nicolás

Comment: This should go on the Quantopian web site, not here.

Comment: I would log an issue in their GitHub repository: https://github.com/quantopian/zipline/issues